# Trying to set conditional based on var type in ansible

Tags: ansible

I can't seem to find a filter for matching a string versus a list versus a dictionary.  My goal is to run different task blocks based on a given variable is a certain variable type.  Here is how it would be wrote up:

```
- name: BLOCK of stuff based on our var is a string
  when: var | type == 'string'
  block:
    # bunch of tasks

- name: BLOCK of stuff based on our var is a list
  when: var | type == 'array'
  block:
    # bunch of tasks

- name: BLOCK of stuff based on our var is a dictionary
  when: var | type == 'dict'
  block:
    # bunch of tasks
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a look at the [built-in jinja2 tests](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#builtin-tests). With those available, the only difficulty is that there is no test to specifically find lists. So you have to check for vars being sequences and exclude strings and dicts.

Here is an example playbook:

```yaml
--
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    test_vars:
      - "I'm a string"
      - ['I', 'am', 'a', 'list']
      - {this: is, a: dict}
      - 10  # This is an integer
      - 2.34  # and here we have a float

  tasks:
    - name: Check if var is a string
      debug:
        msg: this is a string
      when: item is string
      loop: "{{ test_vars }}"

    - name: Check if var is a list
      debug:
        msg: this is a list
      when:
        - item is sequence
        - item is not string
        - item is not mapping
      loop: "{{ test_vars }}"

    - name: Check if var is a dict
      debug:
        msg: this is a dict
      when: item is mapping
      loop: "{{ test_vars }}"
```

which gives:

```
PLAY [localhost] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Check if var is a string] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=I'm a string) => {
    "msg": "this is a string"
}
skipping: [localhost] => (item=['I', 'am', 'a', 'list']) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'this': 'is', 'a': 'dict'}) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=10) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=2.34) 

TASK [Check if var is a list] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost] => (item=I'm a string) 
ok: [localhost] => (item=['I', 'am', 'a', 'list']) => {
    "msg": "this is a list"
}
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'this': 'is', 'a': 'dict'}) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=10) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=2.34) 

TASK [Check if var is a dict] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost] => (item=I'm a string) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=['I', 'am', 'a', 'list']) 
ok: [localhost] => (item={'this': 'is', 'a': 'dict'}) => {
    "msg": "this is a dict"
}
skipping: [localhost] => (item=10) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=2.34) 

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```